# Shrinking size to fit the page while saving .nb as .tex file

Tags: fonts, latex

While converting my .nb outcome to .tex file, I face a problem. The `out lines` in the code are too long. That is why, they are out of PDF page produced from compiling .tex file. I cannot see the whole line in that PDF file as the `out lines` are too long . How should I solve this problem?